# Using property file in maven

Tags: java, maven, properties

I don't quite understand how it can be used. There is a property defined in the file. I try to use maven property plugin to read it and save. The property is used in the liquibase plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <files>
          <file>src/main/resources/properties/app.properties</file>
        </files>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db/config/${env}-data-access.properties</propertyFile>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <migrationSqlOutputFile>src/main/resources/db/gen/migrate.sql</migrationSqlOutputFile>
        <!--<logging>debug</logging>-->
        <logging>info</logging>
        <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
        <!--<verbose>false</verbose>-->
        <dropFirst>true</dropFirst>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

1. According to the documentation in order to read property and save it I have to run: `mvn properties:read-project-properties`. But I'm getting the following error in this case:

   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties (default-cli) on project SpringWebFlow: 
   The parameters 'files' for goal org.codehaus.mojo:properties-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-2:read-project-properties are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

I've changed pom.xml, removed the `<execution>` section and moved the `<configuration>` section:

```
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
  <configuration>
    <files>
        <file>src/main/resources/properties/app.properties</file>
    </files>
  </configuration>
```

Ok. now, when I run mvn properties:read-project-properties the error disappeared. But where in this case the property is saved? Cause when I start the following maven goal:

```
mvn liquibase:update
```

I can see that the ${env} property is not defined. Liquibase tries to use the `src/main/resources/db/config/${env}-data-access.properties` file.

What am I doing wrong? How to read a property from the file, so it could be accessible from different maven plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "mvn liquibase:update" is a special plugin goal and is not part of the maven life cycle. So it never passes the initialize phase and so the property plugin is not executed.

The following will work

```
mvn initialize liquibase:update
```

One solution would be to call liquibase:update in one of the maven lifecylce phases like compile, package ..., but then it would be executed on every build.

Or you use the maven-exec plugin to call "initialize liquibase:update" from maven. Or you create a profile were you bind the liquibase:update to the lifecylce phase initialize and the udate is executed when you call

```
mvn initialize -Pliquibase
```

I do not know a better solution to this problem and I could not find a suitable solution for this.

For reference:
[Maven lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Comment: thanks for your answer. Don't you know, is there a way to throw an exception in maven if a property is not defined? The user may run mvn liquibase:update and I'd like to stop building process and display what's wrong. Otherwise it may take to long to resolve the problem.

Comment: I know the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/) but this should have the same problem as above. You bind it to a life cycle phase of maven not to a specific goal of the liquibase plugin. So my only idea would be to call liquibase via the maven-antrun-plugin and use an ant "<fail message="'env' property must be set" unless="env"/>" or create a wrapper script that your users use for database migration and not allow them to call directly mvn liquibase:*.